# Hashicorp Vault unsealing error through Ansible

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to deploy Hashicorp Vault through Ansible. I have managed to install it and do the initial setup and generate the 5 unseal keys along with the root token. However I am getting errors when trying to unseal it through ansible. I have tried various things to get this to work but every time I get a time out error. I can't even run it through terminal, I get the same errors. Below are all the different ways I have tried to unseal Vault:

Method 1

```
- name: unseal vault
  uri:
    url: "http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal"
    method: PUT
    body: "{{ item }}"
    body_format: json
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200
  become: no
  loop:
    - "{{ key3.stdout }}"
    - "{{ key4.stdout }}"
    - "{{ key5.stdout }}"
```

Method 2:

```
 - name: unseal vault 1
   shell: |
     vault operator unseal {{ key4.stdout }} 
     vault operator unseal {{ key5.stdout }}
     vault operator unseal {{ key3.stdout }}
   environment:
     VAULT_ADDR: "http://172.0.0.1:8200"
```

Method 3 repeated 3 times:

```
 - name: unseal the vault
   become: yes
   command: vault operator unseal {{ key4.stdout }}
   environment:
     VAULT_ADDR: "http://172.0.0.1:8200"
```

I have verified that the key variable that I am getting from my file is correct.

This is the error that I get for method 1:

```
failed: [172.26.1.238] (item=2q2h3y6XsztNEToISMADvbZ5XOugvi7NMHkfiarQq8bN) => {"changed": false, "content": "", "item": "2q2h3y6XsztNEToISMADvbZ5XOugvi7NMHkfiarQq8bN", "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error timed out>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal"}
```

This is the error I get for method 2:

```
fatal: [172.26.1.238]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "vault operator unseal jwmGkN2O5t0JvAI2+82I9WAJuEL1PEG7sbkk8lmao+2B\n vault operator unseal 2q2h3y6XsztNEToISMADvbZ5XOugvi7NMHkfiarQq8bN\n vault operator unseal J74KbqOcqi6CBAB95PRy9kZF77Q7T2XAFWd7amQk1uP+", "delta": "0:01:30.078433", "end": "2018-12-02 00:53:45.609747", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2018-12-02 00:52:15.531314", "stderr": "Error unsealing: Put http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 172.0.0.1:8200: i/o timeout\nError unsealing: Put http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 172.0.0.1:8200: i/o timeout\nError unsealing: Put http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 172.0.0.1:8200: i/o timeout", "stderr_lines": ["Error unsealing: Put http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 172.0.0.1:8200: i/otimeout", "Error unsealing: Put http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 172.0.0.1:8200: i/o timeout", "Error unsealing: Put http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 172.0.0.1:8200: i/o timeout"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

This is the error I get for method 3:

```
fatal: [172.26.1.238]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["vault", "operator", "unseal", "jwmGkN2O5t0JvAI2+82I9WAJuEL1PEG7sbkk8lmao+2B"], "delta": "0:00:30.025966", "end": "2018-12-02 00:58:28.997154", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2018-12-02 00:57:58.971188", "stderr": "Error unsealing: Put http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 172.0.0.1:8200: i/o timeout", "stderr_lines": ["Error unsealing: Put http://172.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 172.0.0.1:8200: i/o timeout"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? I have tried to follow some guides online and also other peoples code from GitHub but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Three of five distinct _people_ should do the unseal, manually, individually.  If you have a quorum of unseal keys in a single place you're misusing them.  You probably can't have Ansible automatically unseal Vault because of this.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the reply. I understand this however for the first time set up we would like Ansible to unseal the Vault for us. The files storing the keys is moved and deleted and therefore kept secure. Also another issues is that I can't run the same command through the terminal to unseal Vault. Surely this should be something that I should be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is embarrassing however I think this might help people trying to do the same thing. So I can confirm that method 2 for sure works. The others may also work but I haven't tested them. The only thing I had to change to make it work was to change the VAULT_ADDR value to 127.0.0.1:8200 not 172.0.0.1:8200. Silly mistake but its costed me over 2 days to work out. So I hope anybody else learns from this.

Thanks